# How to avoid "-" when reading csv file with Pandas converting the column into a int or flot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading a CSV file where some columns include the character "-", meaning Pandas see the columns as "objects" and not "int/float64". Is there a way to replace "-" with either 0 or NaN when reading the file?

I'm able to change the "-" to 0 by writing "df = df.replace('-', 0)" but then I'm not able to convert the columns into int/float afterwards due to the Danish thousand separator/decimal problem.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, skiprows=3, decimal=',', thousands='.')
df = df.replace('-', 0)

11-01-2021,657,117.583,"2,02",-,-,-
12-01-2021,462,118.045,"2,03",-,-,-
13-01-2021,12.729,130.774,"2,24",-,-,-
14-01-2021,17.897,148.671,"2,55",-,-,-
15-01-2021,15.206,163.877,"2,81",5,5,"0,0001"
16-01-2021,4.612,168.489,"2,89",7,12,"0,0002"
17-01-2021,2.539,171.028,"2,93",717,729,"0,01"
18-01-2021,3.883,174.911,"3,00",2.147,2.876,"0,05"
19-01-2021,2.482,177.393,"3,04",2.105,4.981,"0,09"
20-01-2021,1.508,178.901,"3,07",1.898,6.879,"0,12"
21-01-2021,1.531,180.432,"3,10",2.368,9.247,"0,16"
22-01-2021,657,181.089,"3,11",5.685,14.932,"0,26"
23-01-2021,772,181.861,"3,12",7.129,22.061,"0,38"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `na_values` parameter:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas

csv = StringIO("""\
11-01-2021,657,117.583,"2,02",-,-,-
12-01-2021,462,118.045,"2,03",-,-,-
13-01-2021,12.729,130.774,"2,24",-,-,-
14-01-2021,17.897,148.671,"2,55",-,-,-
15-01-2021,15.206,163.877,"2,81",5,5,"0,0001"
16-01-2021,4.612,168.489,"2,89",7,12,"0,0002"
17-01-2021,2.539,171.028,"2,93",717,729,"0,01"
18-01-2021,3.883,174.911,"3,00",2.147,2.876,"0,05"
19-01-2021,2.482,177.393,"3,04",2.105,4.981,"0,09"
20-01-2021,1.508,178.901,"3,07",1.898,6.879,"0,12"
21-01-2021,1.531,180.432,"3,10",2.368,9.247,"0,16"
22-01-2021,657,181.089,"3,11",5.685,14.932,"0,26"
23-01-2021,772,181.861,"3,12",7.129,22.061,"0,38"
""")

df = pandas.read_csv(
    csv, header=None, decimal=',',
    thousands='.', na_values=['-'],
    parse_dates=[0],
).fillna(0)
```

`df.info()` gives me:

```
RangeIndex: 13 entries, 0 to 12
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   0       13 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 1   1       13 non-null     int64         
 2   2       13 non-null     int64         
 3   3       13 non-null     float64       
 4   4       13 non-null     float64       
 5   5       13 non-null     float64       
 6   6       13 non-null     float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4), int64(2)
memory usage: 856.0 bytes
```

And the dataframe itself:

```
             0      1       2     3       4        5       6
0   11-01-2021    657  117583  2.02     0.0      0.0  0.0000
1   12-01-2021    462  118045  2.03     0.0      0.0  0.0000
2   13-01-2021  12729  130774  2.24     0.0      0.0  0.0000
3   14-01-2021  17897  148671  2.55     0.0      0.0  0.0000
4   15-01-2021  15206  163877  2.81     5.0      5.0  0.0001
5   16-01-2021   4612  168489  2.89     7.0     12.0  0.0002
6   17-01-2021   2539  171028  2.93   717.0    729.0  0.0100
7   18-01-2021   3883  174911  3.00  2147.0   2876.0  0.0500
8   19-01-2021   2482  177393  3.04  2105.0   4981.0  0.0900
9   20-01-2021   1508  178901  3.07  1898.0   6879.0  0.1200
10  21-01-2021   1531  180432  3.10  2368.0   9247.0  0.1600
11  22-01-2021    657  181089  3.11  5685.0  14932.0  0.2600
12  23-01-2021    772  181861  3.12  7129.0  22061.0  0.3800
```

If the values are genuinely null, you can omit the `.fillna(0)` step.

Comment: Wow, that was exactly what I was looking for! Brilliant! Very much appreciated